# MSBuild pattern matching for test dlls

Tags: msbuild

I have a CreateItem task to match unit test assembly(s):

```
<CreateItem Include="%(Solution.RelativeDir)**\bin\$(Configuration)\*Test*.dll">
    <Output ItemName="TestDlls" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>
```

This matching dll(s) like:

- Company.Product.Component1.Test.dll
- Company.Product.Component2.UnitTests.dll
- Company.Product.UnitTestFramework1.dll
- Company.Product.UnitTestFramework2.dll

My question is how to change the matching pattern to select only unit test (that have Test, Tests, UnitTest or UnitTests naming convention) but no framework dll(s).

Comment: Is this not what it's doing already?  Which "framework dlls" is it including currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add Test.dll and Tests.dll incrementally. The following would do what you want:

```
<CreateItem Include="%(Solution.RelativeDir)**\bin\$(Configuration)\*Test.dll">
    <Output ItemName="TestDlls" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem> 
<CreateItem Include="%(Solution.RelativeDir)**\bin\$(Configuration)\*Tests.dll">
    <Output ItemName="TestDlls" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Alternatively, you can add use your original item definition, and after that remove those files that match framework pattern. E.g.:

```
<CreateItem Include="%(Solution.RelativeDir)**\bin\$(Configuration)\*Test*.dll">
    <Output ItemName="TestDlls" TaskParameter="Include"/>
</CreateItem> 
<CreateItem Remove="*Framework*.dll" />
```